# How can I get the immediate parent of HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code:

```
<a href="">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square cbutton--effect-marko cbutton--click"></i>
</a>
```

How can I get the `a` tag? When I use `.parent()`

The result is:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.html }
```

Comment: Share your jquery code here

Comment: `when i use .parent()` BUT on which object do you call it???

Comment: Do you mean `$('i').parent('a')`?

Comment: @KilianStinson yes in the a tag

Comment: @A.Wolff this is the code   var parenTag = $('i').parent('a');

Comment: @dorsafdhouibi So obviously you call this code before DOM is ready or element is added to the DOM. You need tp provide more context to your question. Now anyway, try: `$(function(){console.log($('i').parent('a'));});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments you probably execute your JavaScript before your HTML finished loading. So there is no `i` or `a` element at that moment.

Either use the `document.ready` method from jQuery, here as shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    var parenTag = $('i').parent('a');
});
```

Or place your JavaScript code **below** your HTML code.

```
<a href="">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square cbutton--effect-marko cbutton--click"></i>
</a> 

<script>
    $(function() {
        var parenTag = $('i').parent('a');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

a tag is the parent of i tag, if you can access to i tag this should work.

```
$('i').parent();
```